# Submitting two form in which form2 input values depend on form1 inputs value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, payment-gateway

We are going to create a service form , in which customer can enter details, select service and pay cash .

> -> Only one form is shown to user ->user select service with price and fill the other detail->Submitting the details , so data's are saved in
>   backend->After saving data, form2 need to work automatically ,but the
>   second form input value is depend on the first form input values and
>   cash .

1. Which is the best way to implement this ?, two form in same page or different page ?
2. Can i use ajax for this so that customer need to stay in same page ?

we nee to hide our merchant id , merchant secret from inspect element

Please give example .
please see my two forms 
Form-1

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="form1">
 Your name<input type="text" name="cl_name">
 Service < input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="10"> Wash
 < input type="checkbox" name="check-2" value="10"> clean

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Form-2

```
 <form method="post" action="paymet_gateway_url"  id="form2">
Name <input type="text" value="Form1 your name value" name="p_name" id="p_name">
Value<input type="text" value="Form1 service value (either 10 or 20 )" name="p_cash" id="p_cash">
<inpu type="hidden" value="return url" name="p_r_url">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Only one form submit -> Do your logic over server -> redirect on specific page as per the status...

Comment: AJAX uses Javascript, and it will allow the user to stay on the same page.

Comment: Could you please a simple ,basic example for to solve this . It will really help to us .Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: two services have different cash, so that i need to make the cash in payment gate way form dynamic.

Comment: `Ajax or JavaScript` wtf?

Comment: @Gothdo Removed that part .

Comment: @Cindy Meister  Please see my question now . Please don't make it as hold question

Comment: @greg-449 Please see my question now . Please don't make it as hold question

Comment: @EdChum Please see my question now . Please don't make it as hold question

Comment: @RRR Please see my question now . Please don't make it as hold questio

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different ways...

1. You can use PHP Wraper to hide your merchant id

***for Example:***

```
payment.php ---> wrper_payment.php ---> payment_gateway_url
```

2. You can use ajax in your order file

***for Example:***

```
order.php ---> payment.php (which has the merchant id) ---> payment_gateway_url
```

Dear, Javascript and ajax are not different, but if you want to make it very much secured, I suggest you use AngularJS, it's not hard to learn and also faster to execute and implement.

3. you can Use action variable in POST to define more than one payments

***For Example: payment.php***

```
<?php
// For ajax use

$output = array('status'=>false,'error'=>''); //for JSON output

$switch($_POST['action']){
    case 'payment1':
        //process payment1
    break;
    case 'payment2':
        //process payment2
    break;
}

//please dont forgot to set the header
header('Content-Type:application/json;)';
echo json_encode($output);
```

***For Example: order.php***

assuming that you are using jQuery for ajax call

```
<Body>
....
<button onclick="payment('payment1');"> Payment Option 1 </button>
<button onclick="payment('payment2');"> Payment Option 2 </button>

<Script type="text/javascript">
function payment(option){
    $.post('payment.php',{action: option},function(data){
        //provide feedback to customer
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

One last thing, do use PHP wrapper because it will hide all your credentials for security...

Best Luck

Comment: Really thank you Marmik .Sorry for asking this, could you please give an very simple example .Just one field first form and the processing of payment gateway demo form[no need to payment gate way form, just other form]. It will certainly help us . I will up vote your answer. But currently i don't have reputation .

Comment: ok sure, I am updating the answer

Comment: Thank you Friend , i will check this code and tell you . Up voted :)

Comment: @Marmik ,Good work . If you can write the complete code it will more help . A form with variable , ajax request processing and handling etc.

Comment: up voted for the idea.

Comment: I got the idea, but in payment, I suggest you also use session and use some session unique id for verification before submission of second form. but I suggest you can do this in 1 ajax call only, if you come to chat I can explain

Answer (score 0):

Ans:

(1) Two form in one page
(2) Of course you can use Ajax
(3) This is an irrelevant question. Because JavaScript has a specific library which is know as JQuery, and Ajax is a JQuery method.

Here is how you can implement the feature.

1. You can create 2 forms in one PHP page, one below another. Form-1(details form) is visible and form-2(payment form) is invisible.
2. User will see form-1 and they will put their details. When he hit the save button then a JQuery event handler will call another function who has ajax call inside it.
3. The ajax method will receive all form-1's data using serialize method, but for that you need to pass the form-1's object to that ajax call.
4. The ajax method will send those data to a php file which can save those data to your database with status=pending.
5. At the success of that ajax call you will call another function which will hide form-1 and show form-2.
6. When user will give input in form-2 then repeat from step-2 to step-5.
7. Use 2nd ajax function for form-2. At the success of 2nd Ajax call show an alert that payment is complete.

Comment: _Ajax is a JQuery method._ what NONSENSE. JavaScript does have ajax.

Comment: But here inspecting the form will show payment gateway credential details like merchant id, merchant secret etc .

Comment: I was talking about jquery api : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/